# Python curses getmaxyx() always returning same value on windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, curses

I am having trouble with using the python curses module for windows. I have used the wheel found [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses) to get a script I had written on my mac to run on my desktop. For now, the script just displays a border around the window using the screen.border() method and another line across the whole width of the display. I displayed the bar across the screen using this:

```
dimensions = screen.getmaxyx()    
screen.addstr(dimensions[0]/2, 0, "-"*dimensions[1])
```

I ran this in a loop, resetting dimensions each time and using getch to check for a curses.KEY_RRESIZE and then running screen.erase() to allow me to resize the window and the script will still work. When I ran this on windows after installing the wheel for python 3.7 (win32 because the amd64 one gave an error) I found that screen.getmaxyx() always returned the same value: the initial screen size, and never changed when I resized the window. I appreciate any help if anyone knows a way to fix this issue, or if I simply cannot use curses on windows, an alternative library for windows. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call resize_term(0, 0) after you get a KEY_RESIZE. (I’m not sure of the exact Python mapping.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. One thing to note is that KEY_RESIZE does not work on windows, and you must determine a resize by doing this:                               resize = curses.is_term_resized(y, x)
        if resize:
            curses.resize_term(0,0)
            screen.erase()

Answer (score 0):

That ("on windows") is probably using PDCurses, which doesn't have a way to automatically update the screensize (e.g., as done with POSIX-based ncurses's `SIGWINCH` handler).  Rather, it detects the window-size change and the application can call **`is_termresized`** to decide whether to tell the library to change the data structures to match using **`resize_term`**.

The python wrapper doesn't use that.